# iOS: SocketRocket Mach-o Linker Error

Tags: ios, linker-errors, socketrocket

I'm trying to use SocketRocket for an iOS project, I'm developing...
I've been going by the instructions on [Socket Rocket - Installing iOS](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket#installing-ios)
and using the provided chat example as a guide, but when I use:

```
_webSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://localhost:9000/chat"]]];
```

It throws two Mach-O Linker error:

1: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SRWebSocket", referenced from:
Objc-class-ref in HTViewController.o
Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

2: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

As far as I can tell, I've included the correct frameworks/dylibs (as mentioned on the GitHub) and I've added -ObjC to the "other linker flags" option... Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must build the `SRWebSocket` library with i386 architecture.

You can avoid these kind of erros by using package manager like [`Cocoapods`](http://cocoapods.org) for XCode.
They also have `SRWebSocket` library in [`SocketRocket`](http://cocoapods.org/?q=socketrocket) package.

**EDIT:**

If that version is not what you want, you can fork the [`Cocoapods Specs`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) repository and upgrade the Pod to latest `SocketRocket` version.

Then you can also add your forked repo to your local Cocoapods installation using `pod repo` command.

Comment: I tried using the SocketRocket I could find on Cocoapods (SocketRocket 0.2.0, found by searching on Cocoapods), but seems like it might be an old version, as it not ARC-"ified" and has deprecated functions...